# Cannot resize rootfs partition on a emmc memory

Tags: partitioning, gparted, fdisk

I have a emmc memory containing a working Ubuntu system. I want to connect it to my Ubuntu PC and shrink the rootfs partition in order to create a new partition in the resulting free space. I tried both with gparted (using the resize GUI and clicking on Apply) and fdisk but the filesystem gets corrupted. This is the commands I used with fdisk (the rootfs partition is in /dev/sdb5):

- fdisk /dev/sdb
- d 5
- n
- partition number: 5
- first sector: as default
- last sector: +12G
- w

Then running `e2fsck /dev/sdb5`:

> The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 3784187 blocks
>   The physical size of the device is 3145728 blocks Either the
>   superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt! Abort?

These operations used to work with a microSD card instead of the emmc memory. What could be the reason?

Comment: So what have you done with `gparted` so far, and when? Before or after running `fdisk`?

Comment: I used the GUI to resize the partition. I did it after a new flash, with a clean Ubuntu installation

Answer (score 1):

`fdisk` can be used to manipulate partition tables. But `fdisk` does not manipulate what's in the partition. A partition usually contains a file-system, the size of the file-system needs to be reduced before you reduce the size of the partition with `fdisk`.

- increase partition size: use `fdisk` first and then `resize2fs`
- reduce partition size:   use `resize2fs` first and then `fdisk`

If you already created a new formatted partition in the new unallocated space, your file-system will be damaged, probably beyond repair. A part of your file-system would be overwritten.

If you didn't create a new formatted partition yet, you can attempt to repair the damage:

Increase the size of the partition with `fdisk`, at least to it's former size, so that the file-system fits properly in it, then run `e2fsck` on that partition again to check the consistency of the file-system. If it's ok, you can start over with resizing the file-system with `resize2fs` first and reducing the size of the partition with `fdisk` in the second step.

---

Maybe better to use GParted to manage your partitions, Gparted takes care of all the necessary steps and adapts the file-system size to the new partition size automatically.

Comment: I used gparted first, but I got the same problem. That's why I tried with fdisk

Comment: @firion Your file-system might be corrupted before your first attempt with GParted, try the solution I described. I can't guarantee that it solves the problem, but worth to try. How full with data was the partition before? You can't make the partition smaller than the data it has to hold.

Comment: It was a clean Ubuntu that I had just flashed. I am getting the same problem even when I try to grow the partition. For example, if I have a 2GB partition with the rootfs and some unallocated space, if I grow it with gparted and then run e2fsck, I get the error and the filesystem is corrupted.